# how to return a boolean after completion of coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Boolean method inside that some nested method, I want to return that boolean value after completion of all methods but it first executes that boolean value and returns that.
It prints->Entered, completed and started, end.

```
  fun syncAll(): Boolean {
 
    Log.d(TAG, "syncAll: Entered")
   val job= Coroutines.io {
        Log.d(TAG, "syncAll: started")
        method1()
        method2()
        method3()
        Log.d(TAG, "syncAll: end")
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "syncAll: completed")

    return job.isCompleted
}
```

Comment: the `syncAll` function should be `suspend` and `isSuccess` value must be set inside a coroutine.

Comment: I made suspend but  alsoit directly executes boolean value

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `syncAll()` `suspend` function and call it from `CoroutineScope` that is at the calling site.

Inside `syncAll()` you can use `withContext()` to await result from different methods running on different coroutine(s).

Comment: then how to return that?

Comment: Take a look at this. https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html

Answer (score 0):

`syncAll` should be a suspend function:

```kotlin
suspend fun syncAll(): Boolean {
    println("sync: started")
    val job = Job()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job).launch {
        delayFunction(1000)
        delayFunction(2000)
        delayFunction(3000)
        println("sync: end")
    }.join() //Suspends the coroutine until this job is complete
    println("sync: completed")
    return job.complete()
}

suspend fun delayFunction(d: Long) {
    delay(d)
}
```

you have to call this function inside a coroutine:

```kotlin
val job = Job()
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job).launch {
    val result = syncAll()
    println("sync: finished: $result")
}
```

result:

```
sync: started
sync: end //after 6 seconds
sync: completed
sync: finished: true
```